# default python is system version despite conda path appearing first

Tags: python, path, conda

Having looked at several answers to questions about switching default python versions, I understand that the order of directories in the `$PATH` variable determines which python version will get used.

I want the default python on my mac to be the conda-installed version. I know it is installed along with two other system versions because `where python` returns

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/Users/jeff/opt/miniconda3/bin/python
```

and `conda list` shows the python version I want to use. Moreover, when I run `echo $PATH` I see

```
~/opt/miniconda3/bin:/libexec/gnubin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:~/opt/miniconda3/bin:/Users/jeff/opt/miniconda3/bin:/Users/jeff/opt/miniconda3/condabin:/libexec/gnubin
```

So, shouldn't this mean that the conda installation of python should be the default since it appears first in the `$PATH` variable? However when I run `which python` I get `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`.

I'm sure this is elementary but it seems to conflict with the answers I've been seeing.

Comment: I think you set your path wrong. The tilde shouldn't actually appear in the path; it should have been expanded to your actual home directory during the assignment.

Comment: There appear to be multiple attempts (both successful and unsuccessful) to add the same directory later in the path.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by running `conda deactivate` followed by `conda activate base`.